# Should not there be vendor directory under css in H5BP template?

Tags: html5boilerplate

That will be useful in keeping the vendor specific CSS files e.g. bootstrap files or jQuery UI  CSS files.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML5 Boilerplate is meant to be a good starting point for *any* new web project.

The JavaScript files in `/js/vendor` are appropriate starting tools for use on anything new (jQuery and Modernizr).

If the Bootstrap CSS files were added to `/css/vendor` that would be inappropriately suggesting Bootstrap is appropriate for any new project (it's not).

So only thing we could do is add an empty `/css/vendor` folder, which would cause confusion. Unless you can think of some CSS that is appropriate for any new project (like [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) which is already included).